# python: subsetting dataframe using multiple level index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to subset a dataframe using a multilevel index. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['CA', 'WA', 'CO', 'AZ'] * 3,
                   'office_id': range(1, 7) * 2,
                   'sales': [np.random.randint(100000, 999999)
                             for _ in range(12)]})

df2=df.groupby(['state', 'office_id']).agg({'sales': 'sum'})

                  sales
state office_id        
AZ    2          839507
      4          373917
      6          347225
CA    1          798585
      3          890850
      5          454423
CO    1          819975
      3          202969
      5          614011
WA    2          163942
      4          369858
      6          959285
```

As you can see, df2 contains multilevel index with state and office_id. For df2, I would like to subset the dataframe by using the multindex find the following:

1) only state = AZ

2) only office_id <4

3) state = CA and office_id = 5

Historically I would rest the index in the dataframe and subset by columns, but that is not efficient.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use index's `.get_level_values` based indexing i.e an example

```
df2.loc[(df2.index.get_level_values(0)=='AZ')]
# Also you can specify the name i.e df2.loc[(df2.index.get_level_values('state')=='AZ')]
                 sales
state office_id        
AZ    2          469728
      4          398925
      6          704669

df2.loc[(df2.index.get_level_values(0)=='CA') & (df2.index.get_level_values(1)<4)]

                  sales
state office_id        
CA    1          105244
      3          116514
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method:

My df2 is a little different because of the random numbers:

```
df2
                  sales
state office_id        
AZ    2          399569
      4          784863
      6          161690
CA    1          324148
      3          631289
      5          917734
CO    1          380714
      3          289783
      5          682802
WA    2          941091
      4          804442
      6          379563
```

Only Arizona offices:

```
df2.query('state == "AZ"')
                  sales
state office_id        
AZ    2          399569
      4          784863
      6          161690
```

Only office ids less than 4:

```
df2.query('office_id < 4')

                  sales
state office_id        
AZ    2          399569
CA    1          324148
      3          631289
CO    1          380714
      3          289783
WA    2          941091
```

California and office id = 5

```
df2.query('state == "CA" & office_id == 5')
                 sales
state office_id        
CA    5          917734
```

Comment: You can refer to unnamed indexes with `ilevel_0`, `ilevel_1`. [Doc ref.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax)

Comment: But the `ilevel` names only work if the indices have no names. Set `df2.index.names = [None, None]` and then this `df2.query('ilevel_0 == "AZ"')` will work.

Comment: wouldn't that be nice if you update the same.in the answer.. Its always better to make the solution a generalized version.

Comment: Is it also possible to subset the dataframe to get e.g. two states (AZ and CA)?

Comment: `df2.query('state in ["CA", "AZ"]')`